# Multiple pendulum - simplified equation

Tags: game-physics

Could someone help me with a mathematical formula for N connected pendulums?
Some simplified approach, because I know that for 3 pendulums the formula is huge.

Comment: 1) off-topic since it has nothing to do with programming. 2) which formula? Oscillation period, equation of motion, energy? 3) the EoM for 3 pendulums is not "huge"; you're unlikely to be able to handle more complex systems if you think so.

Comment: I think it has to do with game-physics, not programming.
Here is a link where i got inspiration for the double pendulum:
https://www.myphysicslab.com/pendulum/double-pendulum-en.html
I would need the angular velocity: θn''.
θ1'' = −g (2 m1 + m2) sin θ1 − m2 g sin(θ1 − 2 θ2) − 2 sin(θ1 − θ2) m2 (θ2'2 L2 + θ1'2 L1 cos(θ1 − θ2))/L1 (2 m1 + m2 − m2 cos(2 θ1 − 2 θ2)), and θ2'' =...
So, I would need sth like this, but for a n pendulum system, and maybe some mathematical methods to make it simpler, because for the tripple pendulum is even longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Lagrangian formulation:

[image]

Euler-Lagrange equation for each angle:

[image]

Various initial derivatives:

[image]

LHS:

[image]

RHS:

[image]

Equating (and cancelling an `l`):

[image]

So we arrive at a classic `Ax = b` type matrix equation that needs to be solved. This does indeed become very unwieldy even at low values of `N`, so a numerical solution is preferable (e.g. LU decomp.)

---

Test for `N = 2`:

[image]

Solving these (simply multiply `a^-1` with `b` and rearrange) gives the results on [this page](http://www.physicsandbox.com/projects/double-pendulum.html) and [this page](http://rotations.berkeley.edu/the-double-pendulum/), both of which seem to contradict the link you gave.

Comment: Nice. I didn't yet tested you're formulas, but I think you are correct. Thank you